# Java: MimeMessage set send date to multiple recipient

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

How can i set send date while i sent email to multiple recipients? I use setSendData() but in the mail the date is not set.

```
 public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException {
    java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    // Construct the message
    Address[] to = new Address[] {new InternetAddress("abc@abc.com"),
            new InternetAddress("abc@def.com"), 
            new InternetAddress("ghi@abc.com")};
    String from = "me@me.com";
    String subject = "Hello";
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText("Hi,\n\nHow are you?");

        // Send the message.
        Transport.send(msg);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // Error.
    }
}}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: No, everything executes fine without any problems.

Comment: No; you have no way of knowing whether that's true, because you're swallowing and ignoring exceptions.  Don't do that.

Comment: How are you determining that the date is not set?  Why do you think it has anything to do with multiple recipients?  Right before Transport.send, add `msg.writeTo(System.out);` and you'll see exactly what's being sent.  Or turn on [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) to get more detail.

Comment: msg.writeTo(System.out) shows that the date is set. To give more information when i set only one recipient, everything look fine. Problem appears when i set more then one.